# How to pass customized request to controller in spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Generally, when user's form is submitted, **request** is passed to spring controller.

and Controllers are shaped like this
**TestController(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)**

I want to pass "**MyHttpSevletRequest, MyHttpServletResponse**" not "**HttpSevletRequest, HttpServletResponse**".

Is it possible?
I want to know is it possible, and how? in technique.

Don't say that "No need to to that, alternative way is here"

Any answer will be appreiciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can implement your own [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html). However generally when someone wants to introduce his own request/response something else is generally a better solution. Why do you need this?

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I wanted. really thank you. Why I want to do this is to handle various request type. e.g. flex request, extjs, standard request... and so on. If I implement MRequest object, what ever client will be not important. I could get request in consistent way of getParam();

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to do it directly but I know a workaround to get what you intend to do done.

You can use spring aop [methodbeforeadvice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/aop/MethodBeforeAdvice.html) and [afterreturningadvice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/aop/AfterReturningAdvice.html) to get hold of the request and response objects before and after they enter/leave the action method. Basically kind of a request response interceptor you would be doing. In that you can write a transformer method that would take the standard request and response object as input and output you with your custom request and response object(your custom class should implement the HttpServletRequest interface) and then override the request and reponse objects with your custom objects.

Comment: I ever seen before "MRequest, MResponse" in controller. I don't have source of that. but I saw that works well. MRequest differed from Request with addtional method getParam(). I want to implement this. but I can' start, because I don't know how it could be.

Comment: Thats what i suggested, make an interceptor.. recast overwrite your standard request object with your custom request object .. so what ever that will be coming in your controller will be your custom request object and you can use it there as your wish..

Comment: what I accurately want is add a method to HttpServletRequest. Interceptor can do it?

Comment: No interceptor will just be a common point of entrance where all your requests objects will be transformed to custom requests, so that your custom requests objects are available in every action method.